# How take the same DataFrame with a condition on value counts of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas DataFrame with `shape(1000,8)` so i want to make new DataFrame but with condition in one column but not an easy condition it is the value counts of on the specific row, lets say for example we have a column where `df.column1 = [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,8,8,8,8]` i to have the same DataFrame with the sames columns but with condition on column1, i want only rows where the values of column1 are repeated more than 3 times, so i get : `df.column1 = [8,8,8,8]`

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please check my answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

**Here is an example**

```
import pandas as pd
# define df
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['column1'] = [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,8,8,8,8]
df['column2']=range(0,len(df['column1']))
```

**Method 1**

```
new_df=df.groupby('column1').filter(lambda x: x.column1.size>3)
print(new_df)
    column1  column2
8         8        8
9         8        9
10        8       10
11        8       11
```

**Method 2**

or `Groupby.transform` to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
new_df=df[df.groupby('column1').column1.transform('size')>3]
print(new_df)

8         8        8
9         8        9
10        8       10
11        8       11
```

---

**Method 3**

Finally if you want use `value_counts` is better if you use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
new_df=df[df.column1.map(df.column1.value_counts())>3]
print(new_df)
    column1  column2
8         8        8
9         8        9
10        8       10
11        8       11
```

Comment: I have to accept this one its better and Thx to you its amazing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value_counts` and keep only the most frequent values

```
import pandas as pd
# define df
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['column1'] = [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,8,8,8,8] 

#get counts
counts = df['column1'].value_counts()

# keep only counts>3
counts = counts[counts>3]

# get the index to see which column1 values should be kept
to_keep = counts.index

# filter df with only correct values of column1
df.loc[df['column1'].isin(to_keep)]

#   column1
#8  8
#9  8
#10 8
#11 8
```

Comment: I think all this is not necessary

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: here it is not necessary to use  `.index` neither `Series.isin`